# Simple micropython PICO LCD backlight and loop issue

Tags: loops, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

```
from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM,Timer
import framebuf
import time
import os
import gc
##################### FIREBASE ########################
import network
import urequests

BL = 13
DC = 8
RST = 12
MOSI = 11
SCK = 10
CS = 9

'2inch frames'
class LCD_2inch(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        
        self.cs = Pin(CS,Pin.OUT)
        self.rst = Pin(RST,Pin.OUT)
        self.bl =Pin(BL,Pin.OUT)
        self.cs(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000_00,polarity=0, phase=0,sck=Pin(SCK),mosi=Pin(MOSI),miso=None)
        self.dc = Pin(DC,Pin.OUT)
        self.dc(1)
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.height * self.width*2)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.RGB565)
        self.init_display()
        
        self.RED   =   0x07E0
        self.GREEN =   0x001F
        self.BLUE  =   0xF800
        self.WHITE =   0xffff
        self.BLACK =   0x0000



# Example usage:  # Assuming this is your LCD object

    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(0)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([cmd]))
        self.cs(1)

    def write_data(self, buf):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([buf]))
        self.cs(1)

    def init_display(self):
        self.rst(1)
        self.rst(0)
        self.rst(1)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x36)
        self.write_data(0x70)

        self.write_cmd(0x3A) 
        self.write_data(0x05)

        self.write_cmd(0xB2)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x33)
        self.write_data(0x33)

        self.write_cmd(0xB7)
        self.write_data(0x35) 

        self.write_cmd(0xBB)
        self.write_data(0x19)

        self.write_cmd(0xC0)
        self.write_data(0x2C)

        self.write_cmd(0xC2)
        self.write_data(0x01)

        self.write_cmd(0xC3)
        self.write_data(0x12)   

        self.write_cmd(0xC4)
        self.write_data(0x20)

        self.write_cmd(0xC6)
        self.write_data(0x0F) 

        self.write_cmd(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0xA4)
        self.write_data(0xA1)
        
        self.write_cmd(0xE0)
        self.write_data(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0x04)
        self.write_data(0x0D)
        self.write_data(0x11)
        self.write_data(0x13)
        self.write_data(0x2B)
        self.write_data(0x3F)
        self.write_data(0x54)
        self.write_data(0x4C)
        self.write_data(0x18)
        self.write_data(0x0D)
        self.write_data(0x0B)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x23)

        self.write_cmd(0xE1)
        self.write_data(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0x04)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x11)
        self.write_data(0x13)
        self.write_data(0x2C)
        self.write_data(0x3F)
        self.write_data(0x44)
        self.write_data(0x51)
        self.write_data(0x2F)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x20)
        self.write_data(0x23)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x21)

        self.write_cmd(0x11)

        self.write_cmd(0x29)

    def show(self):
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2A)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x01)
        self.write_data(0x3f)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2B)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0xEF)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2C)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(self.buffer)
        self.cs(1)
    def draw_number(self, num, x, y, color):
        # Numbers
       '''numbers = {
            '0': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '1': [(x + 17, y, 10, 90)],
            '2': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 36), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 36, 10, 36), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '3': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '4': [(x, y, 10, 54), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90)],
            '5': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 36), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x + 35, y + 36, 10, 54), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '6': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x + 35, y + 36, 10, 54), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '7': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90)],
            '8': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '9': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 54), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 72, 45, 18)],
            '-': [(x,y+45,20,10)]
        }'''
       numbers = {
    '0': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y, 10, 90), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '1': [(x + 18, y, 10, 90)],
    '2': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x, y + 18, 10, 36), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x + 35, y + 54, 10, 36), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '3': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '4': [(x + 35, y, 10, 54), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90)],
    '5': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x + 35, y + 18, 10, 36), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 36, 10, 54), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '6': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y + 36, 10, 54), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '7': [(x, y, 45, 18), (x, y, 10, 90)],
    '8': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 90), (x, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '9': [(x, y + 72, 45, 18), (x + 35, y, 10, 54), (x, y, 10, 90), (x, y + 36, 45, 18), (x, y, 45, 18)],
    '-': [(x + 25, y + 35, 20, 10)]
    }#Number with lens


       for rect in numbers.get(num, []):
            self.fill_rect(*rect, color)
    #callback
    def polling_timer(timer):
        if not wlan.isconnected():
            self.bl.value(1)
            self.fill(LCD.WHITE)
            for i, number in enumerate(phone_number):  #with lens 
                x = (i % 6) * 50 + 5
                y = ((1 if i < 6 else 0)) * (90 + 20) + 10
                LCD.draw_number(number, x, y, LCD.BLACK)
            
            self.show()
        else:
            self.bl.value(0)  #off backlight  



if __name__=='__main__':

        
    LCD = LCD_2inch()
    gc.collect()
    #color BRG
    LCD.fill(LCD.WHITE)
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)

    # wifi
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        wlan.connect("U+NetA373", "0107004523") 
        print("Waiting for Wi-Fi connection", end="...")
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            print(".", end="")
            time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print(wlan.ifconfig())
        print("WiFi is Connected")

    print("Wifi is connected")

    # Firebase Realtime Database url
    url = "https://embeded-system-e8163-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/"

    initial_string = "0"

    initial_state = {'phone': initial_string}
    gc.collect()
    urequests.patch(url+"/embeded_system/phone.json", json = initial_state).json()

    phone_number = "0"
    
# first number of phone
    gc.collect()
    response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system/phone.json").json()
    while (response == phone_number):
        response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system/phone.json").json()
        gc.collect()
        print("Waiting for the update of phone number...")
    phone_number = response
    pwm = PWM(Pin(BL))
    pwm.freq(1000)
    pwm.duty_u16(32768)#max 65535

    lcd_timer=None
    
    while(1):
        if wlan.isconnected(): # phone number update
            
            LCD.bl.value(0)
            
            gc.collect()
            response = urequests.get(url+"/embeded_system.json").json()
            if (phone_number != response['phone']): 
                phone_number = response['phone']#change value only if data changes
                
            
            if lcd_timer:
                 lcd_timer.deinit()  # stop timer
                 lcd_timer = None
             
        
        if not wlan.isconnected():
            if not lcd_timer:
                lcd_timer=Timer(period=1000,mode=Timer.ONE_SHOT,callback=polling_timer)
                 #demo->if Timer reaches end, 

        
        for i, number in enumerate(phone_number):  #with lens
            x = (310-((i % 6) * 50 + 15) if i<6 else 280-((i % 6) * 50 + 15))
            y = ((0 if i < 6 else 1)) * (90 + 20) + 10
            LCD.draw_number(number, x, y, LCD.BLACK)
        
        LCD.show()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

I want to turn off LCD light when wifi is connected, and if it remained off for several time, then LCD light turns on and exports number data.

What happens->after initializing, backlight offs for sec-> LCD turns on and show the number in firebase. It changes the number value when I change the firebase data, it means it is connected in wifi, but it just break out the loop and activate the timer(I guess) and turn on the LCD.. what's the problem??